# capturing a file into array and using that array in while loop

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, memory, grep

Hi I have to capture a file into an array and then pass that array into the while loop.

I just don't want to execute my script with below while loop because it is taking long time...

```
while read line; do

some actions...

done < file.txt
```

My server has 8 GB ram and out of which 6 GB is always available. So please let me know weather it is a good idea to capture the file of size 100 MB into memory (array) and do operations like grep,sed,awk and etc on it.

If So please let me know how to capture file into array.

If not kindly suggest me another way to increase performance.

Comment: It seems to be a good approach, as this way you will be handling each line separately. Hence, memory will just store the current line, not all the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand...

Do you need something like this ?

```
array=()

# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    i=0
    while read line
    do
        array[i]=$line
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

getArray "file.txt"
for line in "${array[@]}"
do
    # some actions using $line
done
```

---

**EDIT :**

To answer your question, yes it's possible to grep data into an array and push its into another. There is probably a better way to do it, but this works :

```
array2=()

# Split the string in parameter and push the values into the array
pushIntoArray() {
    i=0
    for element in $1
    do
        array2[i]=$element
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done
}

array1=("foo" "bar" "baz")
# Build a string of the elements into the array separated by '\n' and redirect the ouput to grep.
str=`printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | grep "a"`
pushIntoArray "$str"
printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" # Display array2 line by line
```

Output of this snippet:

```
$ ./grep_array.sh
bar
baz
```

Comment: yes exactly...isn't it possible to grep data in an array and send it to another array.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Look at my answer again, I add an example. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks.. Will you please let me know using grep command on file directly is better or the above one is better...Because in loop i have to do many greps

Comment: I don't really know. But "$ grep 'pattern' files" is better than  "$ cat files | grep 'pattern'" (useless use of cat)

Answer (score -2):

You want a while loop. Try this:

```
while read d; do
      echo $d
done < dinosaurs.txt
```

Enjoy